# Can't figure out why my phantomJS script isn't showing the status and taking a picture of the page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am not getting a status of the website nor an error when executing the code when using the URL that is being generated. However, when I use 'http://google.com', the status shows and it takes a screenshot of the page. The URL that is being used is a correct one, when I open the URL in browser it is the Page I want. It seems like the page is unreachable but I am not getting an error nor a status update.

```
var size = 9;
var model = 'CQ2626';

function URL(size, model){

var baseSize = 580;
var shoeSize = size - 6.5;
shoeSize *= 20;
rawSize = shoeSize + baseSize;
var URL = 'http://www.adidas.com/us/' + model + '.html?forceSelSize=' + model + '_' + rawSize;
return URL

};

console.log(URL(size, model));

var page = require('webpage');
var webPage = page.create();

webPage.open(URL(size, model), function(status){

console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    webPage.render('example.png');
  }
 phantom.exit();

});
```

Comment: Just when I was about to write the answer, I found a beautiful blog, I hope that helps: https://blog.whoisrizkipratama.net/download-image-phantomjs/

Comment: @DDM good blog, but irrelevant to this question